# Understanding sudo and possible exploit

Tags: linux, command-line, output

I'm doing some hands on pen testing and following some guides to get an understanding of the tools of the trade. I'm following along with the guide [here](https://download.vulnhub.com/media/zico/rafael_zico-walkthrough.pdf) and I understand everything except for the last page.

I need assistance understanding `sudo -l` below. I know that it details what the current user can do. However, what does the output below mean?

[image]

And how about the command below (excluding touch)? It kind of confuses me because after running that command (exploit?), I was able to get root.

[image]

From my understanding, the line is saying to run the command as root or elevate to root, zip the file called exploit, and place it in tmp/exploit. I believe I'm wrong but that's where my understanding of that line stops.

I'm confused as to how I got root with that command and what that line is doing.

Comment: Please do not post pictures of text; just paste the relevant text.

Comment: It is somewhat remiss of the sysadmins to offer `tar` + `zip`  via `sudo`.  So many attack vectors become possible here, such as using `tar` to write a new `/etc/passwd` / `/etc/shadow` file, for starters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your first question, the indicated lines of output are telling you that you are permitted to run `/bin/tar` and `/usr/bin/zip` via `sudo` as the root user without even needing to provide `zico`'s password.

For your second question, we get the answer from `zip`'s manual page:

```
   --unzip-command cmd
          Use command cmd instead of 'unzip -tqq' to test an archive when the -T option is used.
```

So, since you're privileged to run `zip` as the root user through `sudo`, the exploit is simply telling `zip` "hey, when you're testing this archive, use the command `sh -c /bin/bash` to test it, would you?" and it's helpfully doing so, giving you a root shell.

The `exploit` file is just there to provide `zip` something to compress, so that there would be something to "test".  It's never being *run* or anything and indeed in your demonstration is simply an empty file.

```
$ sudo -u root zip /tmp/exploit.zip /tmp/exploit -T --unzip-command="sh -c /bin/bash"
```

is instructing `sudo` to, as the root user, run this command:

```
$ zip /tmp/exploit.zip /tmp/exploit -T --unzip-command="sh -c /bin/bash"
```

This command will take the file `/tmp/exploit` and put it into a new archive, `/tmp/exploit.zip`.  The `-T` switch tells `zip` to then **T**est the integrity of the archive, and the `--unzip-command` switch is telling `zip` *how* to test the archive.  This last thing is the actual exploit:  because `zip` is being run as root, running `sh -c /bin/bash` gives you a shell as the root user.

Comment: It took me several times to read your answer to get a grasp of this. I appreciate you breaking this down. Last question, --unzip-command="sh -c /bin/bash" is basically saying "I want to test this archive by unzipping the file and then open a shell."?

Comment: No, it's saying "I want you to 'test' this archive by just _giving_ me a shell".  That's the exploit at play here.

Answer (score 2):

Even without `zip`, the `tar` command can be used to break things.  All you need is a tar file with setuid root program inside and then `tar xfp` it.

For example if I can create a tarball with ksh93 with setuid root then I can get root privs

```
$ tar tvf ../foo.tar
-rwsr-xr-x root/root   1519024 2018-11-08 21:32 ksh93
$ sudo tar xvfp ../foo.tar 
ksh93
$ ./ksh93 -c id
uid=500(sweh) gid=500(sweh) euid=0(root) groups=500(sweh),10(wheel),13(news)
$
```

Spot the euid.. I have effective root.

Comment: Hi Steven. I see. I'm still in the process of learning. I would have to say I need more experience/practice to create a setuid root program:( However, I do understand your answer and thanks for that other way of going around to get root.